# The error says "The Left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" in the line for if (x++ =5) and if(++x =7)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

this was one of my test code which we had to sort out the error. The error says "The Left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" in the line for if (x++ =5) and if(++x =7) and i have no idea what i should do.
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 5;
        int y = 0;
        if (x++ = 5) //error
        {
            if (++x = 7) //error
            {
                y = 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("x={0} and y = {1}", x, y);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need to use `==` not `=`

Comment: life saver, thank you. Could you explain why?

Comment: I explained in the answer

Comment: Because `=` means set value, while  `==` means equals

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `==` in the if condition not the `=` so that it can be evaluated to `true` or `false`

```
if (x++ == 5)
    {
        if (++x == 7)
        {
```

Comment: yup now i get it, Thank you